# CakePHP Method BreadcrumbsHelper::templates does not exist

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-4.x

I have followed cakephp version 4  [breadcrumb documentation](https://book.cakephp.org/4/en/views/helpers/breadcrumbs.html#customizing-the-output) for create a simple breadcrumb. But here getting notice templates does not exist.

My effort

```
$this->Breadcrumbs->add(
    'add',
    ['controller' => 'Products', 'action' => 'add']
);

$this->Breadcrumbs->templates([
    'wrapper' => '<nav class="breadcrumbs"><ul{{attrs}}>{{content}}</ul></nav>',
]);


echo $this->Breadcrumbs->render(
    ['class' => 'breadcrumbs-trail'],
    ['separator' => '<i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i>']
);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation is outdated, the method is called `setTemplates()`.

**https://github.com/cakephp/docs/pull/6629**